# Android: Duplicate class found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to update the dependencies of one of my Android projects and I am getting this strange error.

The culprit is this line, for AdMob (I was previously using 20.6.0):

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0"
```

I get a bunch of errors:

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-20.1.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:20.1.1)

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzna found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-20.1.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:20.1.1)

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-20.1.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:20.1.1)

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-20.1.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:20.1.1)

> ...

Here are all the dependencies I'm using in the project's `build.gradle (:app)`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    // Firebase & Crashlytics
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    //Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2"
    // AdMob
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0"
    // Style
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    // Play Core
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    // Billing
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.0.0"
}
```

And the dependencies in `build.gradle (My App)`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1"
    }
}
```

What is causing this error? If I revert `play-services-ads` to 20.6.0 I don't get any error.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 114, accepted):

you need also to update
`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1'),` to

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution! I've been trapped by the fact that I don't get any warning on this line in Android Studio.

Comment: i think, you was be hero for some developers!

Comment: Goob job, bro! tks

Comment: Thanks bro, it take more than half of my day.

Comment: Nice, worked. I used:
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')

Answer (score 18):

As stated in the error message, there are some duplicate classes (most likely also having an incompatible version setting) that you need to resolve/remove. For my case I need to upgrade my Firebase Analytics. This was how I track down the problem:

I ran

```
./gradlew -q app:dependencies
```

to discover the following snippets by searching for `play-services-measurement`:

```
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 -> 1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.3.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0 -> 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:21.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:21.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0 -> 2.7.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0 -> 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0 -> 2.5.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.6.0 -> 1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5 -> 2.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0 -> 2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.1.0 -> 2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 -> 1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.1.0 -> 2.4.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:21.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:20.1.2 (*)
```

```
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.3
|    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3 -> 20.1.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.3
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3 -> 20.1.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0
|    |    |    |         +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0 -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3 -> 20.1.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3 -> 20.1.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0 -> 18.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0 -> 20.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:16.3.2 -> 17.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-installations-interop:16.0.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:18.0.3
```

So obviously the problem is laid within these two direct dependencies of my project `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3` are both specifying a different version of `play-services-measurement`

If we look one step further at the pom file of `play-services-measurement:18.0.3`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-measurement-base</artifactId>
      <version>[18.0.3]</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-measurement-impl</artifactId>
      <version>[18.0.3]</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

It requires strictly 18.0.3 of `base` and `impl` which makes Gradle unable to resolve the problem by itself.

I've chosen to upgrade [firebase analytics](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-analytics/20.1.2) to `20.1.2` and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you, this is *the* way to fix mysterious Duplicate Class errors! Find the clashing main modules (aka direct dependencies) and update one of them until the clash disappears. I can't quite believe the build system is so brittle (and opaque) but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

For me, removing `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'` fixed this headache.

Not sure if you can afford removing it, but i did.

Answer (score -3):

i solved it by
update flutter version and update packages in pubspec.yaml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).