# Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes

Tags: java, android

I'm updating an App in Android Studio (Giraffe) and getting this error many times

**Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0)**

I tried a lot of different approaches to solve this but none worked.

I tried this

https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree

Which created more errors.

Also this
[Error building android: Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0 - Unity 2019.4.40f1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921553/error-building-android-duplicate-class-androidx-annotation-animres-found-in-mod)

[Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909804/duplicate-class-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannel-found-in-modules)

[Android: Duplicate class found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480174/android-duplicate-class-found-in-modules-jetified-play-services-measurement-and)

[Duplicate classes from androidx and com.android.support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support)

My gradle.properties has this lines.

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.nonFinalResIds=false
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

I'm not using Kotlin I only use JAVA; so I deleted this line in build.gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Edit:
I found this on the build gradle, Should I change the classpath? What should I write?

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have default dependencies like below in **build.gradle.kts (Module:app)** file

```
dependencies {
     implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
     implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
     implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
     testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
     androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```